# Why is this function affecting a variable that is not even passed to it?

Tags: python

```
def detectFaceOfImage(self,cascade_path, path):

    print "Detecting facing from image in",path,"..."
    print

    img = cv.imread(path)

    face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier(cascade_path)

    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.5, 1)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        # cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        self.crop_img.append(img[y:y + h, x:x + w])
        self.gray_img.append(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

    print "Finished detecting faces, stored in crop_img and gray_img..."
    print

    self.crop_img, self.gray_img = self.checkAndFixSize(self.crop_img, self.gray_img)
    temp = self.gray_img

    # self.exportImages(crop_img, gray_img)
    temp = self.normalizeImages(temp)
    self.exportImages(self.crop_img, self.gray_img)

def normalizeImages(self, gray_img_here):
    print "Normalizing the gray images..."
    print
    gray_img_numpy = np.array(gray_img_here)
    for i in range(len(gray_img_here)):
        print
        # print "mean of the {}th image", np.mean(gray_img_numpy[i])
        # print "std dev. of the {}th image", np.std(gray_img_numpy[i])
        # print
        gray_img_here[i] = (gray_img_here[i] - np.mean(gray_img_numpy[i]))

    return gray_img_here
def exportImages(self, crop_img, gray_img):

    print "Writing cropped images into directories..."
    print

    for i in range(0, len(crop_img), 1):
        filename = "cropped_images/img{}.jpg".format(i)
        filenamegray = "cropped_gray_images/grayimg{}.jpg".format(i)
        cv.imwrite(filename, crop_img[i])
        cv.imwrite(filenamegray, gray_img[i])

    print("Done!")
```

The issue starts with the line

```
temp = self.gray_img
```

in the `detectFaceOfImage` function. I am passing `temp` to `normalizeImages()`, but somehow even the variable `gray_img` is getting affected by this function.
When I export `gray_img`, it shows the normalized temp images even though `gray_img`'s memory did not get altered in any way. Please help me. I have no idea why is this happening.

Comment: What is `gray_img`? (There's a fair bit of code here, and I can't tell where you initialise it)

Comment: `temp` and `self.gray_img` are the same object. Assigning an object to a new variable does not copy it.

Comment: @doctorlove gray images is a list of 2 D arrays which represent an image. It is initialised globally, and I append to it in detectFaceOfImage

Comment: @khelwood yes I understand that they point to the same memory, but I thought a functions parameters are stored locally only within the scope of the function. And also In all my other functions when I pass other variables, the original variable does not get affected

Comment: The "address" is stored locally, but refers to the outside object. If you pass in an integer that's different to objects. Try the `id` function

Answer (score 1):

If you data is a list, or any other object, you need a deep copy.

Look at this:

```
>>> def mutate(data):
...   data[0]=101
...
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> temp=L
>>> mutate(temp)
>>> temp
[101, 2, 3]
>>> L
[101, 2, 3]
```

If you have

```
>>> L=[1,2,3]
>>> temp=list(L) #<--- deep copy here
>>> mutate(temp)
```

instead this happens:

```
>>> temp
[101, 2, 3]
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

If your type is something other than a `list` just make the type indicated to deep copy.

Comment: thank you! I didnt know that lists work different than other data types and the memory can even be altered within the scope of a function.

Comment: The list isn't different to other object. the assignment `=` tends to refer to the original object. You have to try harder to get a new copy. The `id` function will tell you where they live. If the address is the dsame, they refer to the same thing

Comment: @SharanNarasimhan it's not just list, it's all **mutable** types, of which the most common are: list, dict, set, bytearray

Comment: But generally while passing a variable as a function parameter, I was under the impression that the function creates a local copy only within its scope, so any changes you make dont affect the variable you originally passed, is that wrong? Sorry for my ignorant questions please bear with me :)

Comment: @SharanNarasimhan The function does _not_ create a local copy of the object. The *variable* is a local copy, but the *object it refers to* is the same object as outside the function. Altering a variable is different from altering an object held by a variable.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong in that case. Everything in python gets passed by-reference, rather than by-value. No automagically copying takes places. Maybe understanding is easier if you don't think about variables as "containers holding a value", but rather pointers to objects in memory with a reference counter. Multiple variables may point to the same object in memory, so if this object changes, it is changed for all pointers.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for the clarification! This pass by reference rule does not work with primitive data types , correct? Only with altering an instance of an object ?